# FindStr Extracting Version Number

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a html file, index.html that contains"

Worked, but I would like to improvise this code for the following to print only version of "app4"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <title>Index of /someapp</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /someapp</h1>
<li><a href="app1-1.8.2-base-linux.tar.gz"> app1-1.8.2-base-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app1-1.8.2-base-windows.zip"> app1-1.8.2-base-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app1-1.8.2-linux.tar.gz"> app1-1.8.2-cstrike-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app1-1.8.2-windows.zip"> app1-1.8.2-cstrike-windows.zip</a></l
<li><a href="app1-installer-1.8.2.exe"> app1-installer-1.8.2.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="app2-1.20-am.zip"> app2-1.20-am.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app2-1.21-am.zip"> app2-1.21-am.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app2-1.21.1-am.zip"> app2-1.21.1-am.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.10.0-linux.tar.gz"> app3-1.10.0-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.10.0-mac.zip"> app3-1.10.0-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.10.0-windows.zip"> app3-1.10.0-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.9.2-linux.tar.gz"> app3-1.9.2-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.9.2-mac.zip"> app3-1.9.2-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app3-1.9.2-windows.zip"> app3-1.9.2-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.4-linux.tar.gz"> app4-1.4.4-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.4-mac.zip"> app4-1.4.4-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.4-windows.zip"> app4-1.4.4-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.5-linux.tar.gz"> app4-1.4.5-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.5-mac.zip"> app4-1.4.5-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.5-windows.zip"> app4-1.4.5-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.6-linux.tar.gz"> app4-1.4.6-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.6-mac.zip"> app4-1.4.6-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.4.6-windows.zip"> app4-1.4.6-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.0-linux.tar.gz"> app4-1.5.0-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.0-mac.zip"> app4-1.5.0-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.0-windows.zip"> app4-1.5.0-windows.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.1-linux.tar.gz"> app4-1.5.1-linux.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.1-mac.zip"> app4-1.5.1-mac.zip</a></li>
<li><a href="app4-1.5.1-windows.zip"> app4-1.5.1-windows.zip</a></li>
</ul>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) Port 80</address>

</body></html>
```

How would it possible to get the version numbers of "App4" printed to a file. (Using batch programming and finstr)

In the following manner.

```
1.4.4
1.4.5
1.4.6
1.5.0
1.5.1
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: DOS, Since I am trying to make an installer to download the latest version of the application.

Comment: I added the DOS tag. People get questions in thier queue based on tags. If you dont tag right, no one gets them. [findstr] has 0 followers.

Comment: DOS is an operating system, not a language.

Comment: @GaNi, consider using tag batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=-" %%i  in ("index.html") do (
  echo %%i  >>result.txt
)
```

**APP4**

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%i  in ("index.html") do (
  echo "%%i" | find /i "app4" >nul 2>&1 && ( 
    echo %%j  >>result.txt
  )
)
```

Comment: if the `index.html` is held by another process better stop it.

Comment: and you use the same code (after the revision..) and started only once? Strange because it works with no problems with me...

Comment: Yeap, and I am on Windows 8 x64, the command prompt gets hung up(Duplicate process are generated), I have to forcibly terminate it (taskkill /f /im)

Comment: how exactly did call the  bat? Do you use some external program?

Comment: I don't know why I named the file "find.bat"... Works now, but the problem is, it's not matching "-windows.zip" files. It filters all app4 and also prints "Echo is off"